# How to make a website's JavaScript file inaccessible or hide certain info on it

Tags: javascript, api, security, url, web-applications

I'm currently using GitHub pages to host my website and I'm making a simple web app that requires an API call. The API call is a web url with certain parameters and one of the mandatory parameters is the personal API key issued from the service which they strictly warn to not share with others cause its the equivalent of sharing your password. This service has no public API keys, only account bonded ones.

In my JavaScript file I have a line that goes something like this:

`var api= "https://osu.ppy.sh/api/get_beatmaps?k=[MY API KEY HERE]"`
Where this string is then used in a getJSON call.

Where after the `?k=` is my account tied API which I do not want to share because its the equivalent of giving out my password. I realised that any user can just go on `myname.github.io/js/script.js` and they can view the JavaScript and thus see my API key. Is there a way to make it so this file is unable to be accessed or a way to make it so no one can see my API key.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can isolate this, as in run that code on a server you control and can lock down, the answer is no.

You could also do this "serverless" as in an Amazon Lambda function or equivalent.

Remember, client-side code runs client-side, so if they have access to your key, they have access to your key. The only way around this is to intermediate or proxy the request.